# Expressive Java Function

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I have a working Java app that I am looking to update to use more of Java 8's features.

I have a `Function` as follows:

```
protected static Function<Notification,Notification> 
    coverpageNotification =  n -> n
                        .withMessage("COVERPAGE MESSAGE")
                        .withDate(new Date());
```

and I call it now using:

```
s = new HashSet<Notification>();
checkNotificationStatus(true, coverpageNotification.apply(new Notification()), s);
...
...
```

Instead of saying `coverpageNotification.apply(new Notification())`, is there a more expressive way of doing this using lambdas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no more expressive syntax to call `Function.apply()`

Apart from that, what are you trying to achieve with lambdas? 
In its current form, this does not have any advantage over a simple method:

```
static Notifaction addCoverPage(Notifaction n){
    return n.withMessage("COVERPAGE MESSAGE")
     .withDate(new Date());
}
```

and

```
checkNotificationStatus(true, addCoverPage(new Notification()), s);
```

If you still need a function at some point, you can also turn the method into one:

```
Function<Notification,Notification> x =  SomeClass::addCoverPage;
```

Comment: This is wisdom. Writing lambda expressions for the sake of lambda expressions is ok if you are doing it for the sake of learning, but in practice, their unnecessary use can make code hard to read and maintain.  The idiom used here of using a function + method reference instead of a lambda is a good one.  I use both, and it boils down to which is most readable and carries the most information. A function name used in a method reference is a kind of documentation of what is being done, and that can be more understandable than a bare lambda if the lambda expression is not simple and obvious.